# What does Java hashtablload factor == 1 mean?

Tags: java, load, hashtable

I need a hashtable that doesn't change it's size, because at the beginning I know the size should be N, and the table shouldn't change in the program, so should I set the load factor to 1 to mean don't increase it's size until the size increases to N+1, which I know will never occur ?

To be more specific, I want this : when it reaches N, it shouldn't increase, but if N+1 occurs, then increase size. Is this the right way to set it ?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it actually meant that, needed confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is yes. However to explain a little bit..

The threshold for rehashing is calculated like this

`threshold = (int)(initialCapacity * loadFactor);`

And in the put method rehash is triggered by the following condition.

`if (count >= threshold)`

This is more or less true for HashMap as well. Should you decide to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `java.util.HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`, unless you need the synchronized access. Either provides a constructor for you to set an initial capacity.

The load factor is the upper threshold multiplier for number of items before the table is rehashed.

Comment: Thanks, but it's similar to java doc, yet not answering my question, if I don't want the table to change, should I set the load factor to 1 ?

Comment: You can set the load factor to 1 (the default is 0.75), or provide an initial capacity 30% higher than needed so it won't rehash.

Comment: having a loadfactor of 1 won't stop you from adding more items than the initial capacity, it merely delays the expansion of the internal datastructure.

Comment: Yes but OP just seem to wish to be certain that a rehashing won't occur without the allocated capacity being exceeded.

Comment: Oh okay, just clarifying; I couldn't understand the original post.